# Clear queue when discord.js bot gets disconnected

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am new to discord.js and I followed a tutorial to create a simple music bot.
My only issue is that when the bot gets disconnected from a voice channel by a user, the queue doesn't stop, and when I try playing a song, it won't reconnect and the join command works but it doesn't play anything.
How do I clear the queue when the bot gets disconnected.

[image: disconnect picture]

My code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const yts = require('yt-search');
const token = '/';
const client = new Discord.Client();

const queue = new Map();

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log('Ready!');
});

client.once('reconnecting', () => {
 console.log('Reconnecting!');
});

client.once('disconnect', () => {
 console.log('Disconnect!');
});

client.on('message', async (message) => {
 if (message.author.bot) return;
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

 const serverQueue = queue.get(message.guild.id);

 if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}play`)) {
  execute(message, serverQueue);
  return;
 } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}skip`)) {
  skip(message, serverQueue);
  return;
 } else if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}stop`)) {
  stop(message, serverQueue);
  return;
 } else {
  message.channel.send('You need to enter a valid command!');
 }
});

async function execute(message, serverQueue) {
 const args = message.content.split(' ');

 const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 if (!voiceChannel)
  return message.channel.send(
   'You need to be in a voice channel to play music!'
  );
 const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
 if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) {
  return message.channel.send(
   'I need the permissions to join and speak in your voice channel!'
  );
 }

 let song;
 if (ytdl.validateURL(args[1])) {
  const songInfo = await ytdl.getInfo(args[1]);
  song = {
   title: songInfo.title,
   url: songInfo.video_url,
  };
 } else {
  const { videos } = await yts(args.slice(1).join(' '));
  if (!videos.length) return message.channel.send('No songs were found!');
  song = {
   title: videos[0].title,
   url: videos[0].url,
  };
 }

 if (!serverQueue) {
  const queueContruct = {
   textChannel: message.channel,
   voiceChannel: voiceChannel,
   connection: null,
   songs: [],
   volume: 5,
   playing: true,
  };

  queue.set(message.guild.id, queueContruct);

  queueContruct.songs.push(song);

  try {
   var connection = await voiceChannel.join();
   queueContruct.connection = connection;
   play(message.guild, queueContruct.songs[0]);
  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
   queue.delete(message.guild.id);
   return message.channel.send(err);
  }
 } else {
  serverQueue.songs.push(song);
  return message.channel.send(`${song.title} has been added to the queue!`);
 }
}

function skip(message, serverQueue) {
 if (!message.member.voice.channel)
  return message.channel.send(
   'You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!'
  );
 if (!serverQueue)
  return message.channel.send('There is no song that I could skip!');
 serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function stop(message, serverQueue) {
 if (!message.member.voice.channel)
  return message.channel.send(
   'You have to be in a voice channel to stop the music!'
  );
 serverQueue.songs = [];
 serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end();
}

function play(guild, song) {
 const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
 if (!song) {
  serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
  queue.delete(guild.id);
  return;
 }

 const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
  .play(ytdl(song.url))
  .on('finish', () => {
   serverQueue.songs.shift();
   play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
  })
  .on('error', (error) => console.error(error));
 dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
 serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Have you tried disconnecting the bot via a command and not an administrative action? You can use the `.disconnect()` function to do that.

Comment: Have you tried changing `client.once` to `client.on`?

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca yes, I have a command to disconnect it but my friends keep disconnecting it and I need to restart it and i think clearing the queue when it gets disconnected would fix this

Comment: can you tell me what you actually do when you `${prefix}stop` the bot? As far as I can tell it only sets the `songs` value to an empty array and disconnects the bot from the channel. But when I try to do that in another way it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK there are two things that you need to do in order to make this work.

- Use the correct listener
- delete the queue if the bot gets disconnected

So lets do that

the listener you need to use is `voiceStateUpdate` that tracks all changes to voice channel participants like "mute", "deaf" and (and thats the important part) connects and disconnects. It takes two arguments, `oldState` and `newState`. We need to use both of them.

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => { }
```

Now that we have the listener set up we can fill it.

First we need to check if the channelID of `oldState` is `undefined` or `null`. Both of those indicate that the user joining is connecting and since we only want to act when someone disconnects we need to return if they don't.

```
if (oldState.channelID === null || typeof oldState.channelID == 'undefined') return;
```

Next we need to check if the user who triggers this listener is the bot. If we don't do this every time someone disconnects from any voice channel clear the queue.

```
if (newState.id !== client.user.id) return;
```

and lastly we can clear the queue using the id of the guild.

```
return queue.delete(oldState.guild.id);
```

Now your `voiceStateUpdate` listener should look a litte something like this:

```
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
    // check if someone connects or disconnects
    if (oldState.channelID === null || typeof oldState.channelID == 'undefined') return;
    // check if the bot is disconnecting
    if (newState.id !== client.user.id) return;
    // clear the queue
    return queue.delete(oldState.guild.id);
    
});
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState